# no such module 'PackageDescription' sourcekitd - Ubuntu

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code, swift-package-manager, sourcekit

I am having trouble to configure SourceKit-LSP on Visual Studio Code.
Sourcekit kas issues on fingding 'PackageDescription' module, even it can find some core modules like 'Foundation', 'FoundationXML', 'DispatchIntrospection' etc.

Answer (score 1):

Found help on swift forum.
Here the link to the answer:
[No such module ‘PackageDescription’ sourcekitd](https://forums.swift.org/t/no-such-module-packagedescription-sourcekitd/29406/2?u=mamphir)